# How can I transform a user-defined string into an integer

Tags: c++

I basically ask a user to input a string, let's say they input "ABC" or"DEF"

Then, I want to set a certain integer = 1 if ABC is entered and 2 if DEF is entered.

If anything else is entered, then I want it to say invalid value.

So at the end, I'll have the integer i assigned to 1 or 2 if a valid value was entered.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     string input = "";

// How to get a string/sentence with spaces
cout << "Please enter a valid sentence (with spaces):\n>";
getline(cin, input);
cout << ".\n" << "You entered: " << input << endl << endl;

int m
if(input = ABC)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a map  - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/ .

Comment: For more values, an `unordered_map`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const std::map<std::string, int> lookupTable = { {"ABC", 1}, {"DEF", 2} };
    string input = "";
    int m;

    while(true) {
        cout << "Please enter a valid sentence (with spaces):\n>";
        getline(cin, input);
        std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator it = lookupTable.find(input);
        if (it != lookupTable.end()) {
            m = it->second;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "You entered: " << input << endl << endl;
    cout << "m = " << m << endl;
}
```

Second solution if you want your m const.  This assumes your compiler supports lambda functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const std::map<std::string, int> lookupTable = { {"ABC", 1}, {"DEF", 2} };
    string input = "";
    const int m = [&]() {
        while(true) {
            cout << "Please enter a valid sentence (with spaces):\n>";
            getline(cin, input);
            std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator it = lookupTable.find(input);
            if (it != lookupTable.end())
                return it->second;
        }
    }();

    cout << "You entered: " << input << endl << endl;
    cout << "m = " << m << endl;
}
```

If your compiler does not support the above map initialization then you can use instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

std::map<std::string, int> initializeMap() {
    std::map<std::string, int> map;
    map["ABC"] = 1;
    map["DEF"] = 2;
    // add whatever else here
    return map;
}

int main()
{
    const std::map<std::string, int> lookupTable = initializeMap();
    string input = "";
    int m;

    while(true) {
        cout << "Please enter a valid sentence (with spaces):\n>";
        getline(cin, input);
        std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator it = lookupTable.find(input);
        if (it != lookupTable.end()) {
            m = it->second;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "You entered: " << input << endl << endl;
    cout << "m = " << m << endl;
}
```

Comment: It's a terrible suggestion to ignore the return value of an I/O operation.

Comment: Does not perform to requirements.  If "DEF" is entered loop does not exit.

Comment: Although he did not say it.  I'm sure that if anything but "ABC" or "DEF" is entered, the user must enter again.  I doubt he wants his program to end because of an invalid input.  He said "I want to set a certain integer ... ", which suggests that he wants to continue using that integer afterwards, not end the program due to an invalid input.

Comment: Correct, I want to continue to use the integer. But I was just giving an example. There are more than 2 strings, how would I edit your code accordingly? I guess I should also say that I want 1 to be a double, not integer

Comment: Ok, in that case you should use a map. I'll edit my answer to meet your new requirements.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clearer, thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. The other answer above is giving me errors, but your code seems to not be so I thought maybe yours might work

Comment: error: deducing from brace-enclosed initializer list requires #include <initializer_list>

Comment: Ok, you are using a compiler that does not support that type of initialization.  I'll do it the old way.  But do you want to keep the map const still?

Comment: @prestokeys Are you still here by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Very easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> const v { { "ABC", 1 }, { "DEF", 2 } };

    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
    {
        auto it = v.find(line);

        if (it == v.end())
        {
            std::cout << "Input '" << line << "' is invalid.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Your input value: " << it->second << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With that code, I get an error saying 'it' does not name a type

Comment: @Jack: If you're on an ancient compiler, you need to spell out the type name.

Comment: I am using g++, is that considered ancient?

Comment: @Jack: If it's GCC 4.6, then it's fine.

Comment: What do you mean, spell it out?

Comment: It's the version that comes with Ubuntu 13.04, so it should be pretty new. How is it fine, if the error persists? I am not sure what you mean

Comment: Instead of `auto`, say the type name. It's something like `std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator`.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: I just type g++ a.cpp

Comment: I am still not sure how to get this code to work. I just get errors

Comment: @Jack: `gcc -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 -o program program.cpp`

Comment: I just downloaded g++-4.6 and it still says it does not name a type. Can the code be edited to work properly?

Comment: @Jack: Oh, with GCC 4.6 the language flag is `-std=c++0x`. Why don't you download GCC 4.9 instead... You can also remove the brace initializer from the map and add the elements manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your English spec:

> **”**  set a certain integer = 1 if ABC is entered and 2 if DEF is entered […] if anything else is entered, then I want it to say invalid value.

Expressed in C++:

```
if( s == "ABC" ) { x = 1; }
else if( s == "DEF" ) { x = 2; }
else { cout << "Invalid value." << endl; }
```

If neither of the specified possibilites is true, i.e. in the case of outputting "Invalid value.", then `x` keeps the value it had, which is how I interpret the word “set”.

---

At a higher level of abstraction, it *seems* like you want the user to specify one of two strings, namely “ABC” or “DEF”, which you want to have available as an integer id after the input operation.

Then there are two main possibilities:

- you want the id to indicate also the case where the user specified some other string, e.g. a common value for this, or
- you want the input operation to only return control when the user has inputted one of the two valid strings.

The last case effectively means that input operation must loop or logically fail. Logical failure can be expressed as an exception, or e.g. by calling `std::terminate`.

So as you see there is a range of possibilities here, i.e. above the simple “how do I translate this English to C++” the desired functionality is a bit *under-specified*.